# Lack intellectually or Lacking intellectually

Tags: grammaticality

I came across a phrase on the internet that seemed wrong (surprise):

"[...] especially for those who **lack intellectually**."

In my opinion, this should say "especially for those [who are] **lacking intellectually**", and the first quote uses improper grammar. Am I correct, or is the first quote really a *proper* use of those words together?

Comment: I wouldn't use it, but I couldn't find a source proscribing it. However, I think that "[...] especially for those who are intellectually lacking" is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is fine.

The only difference between *he lacks intellectually* and *he is lacking intellectually* is that one is written in the present, and the other the present continuous.

Similarly 'She speaks *intellectually*' and 'She is speaking *intellectually*'.

*Intellectually* is a perfectly normal adverb.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking specifically about the combination with "lacks" being used in that form. I was thinking that it should be "those who lack intellect" or "those who are lacking intellectually" over the original phrasing.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, if you say 'he lacks intellect', you are turning 'lack' into a transitive verb and 'intellect' becomes its object.But saying 'he lacks intellectually' is an intransitive use of the verb, and grammatically is no different to saying 'he runs slowly'.

Comment: But 'speak' is far more commonly used intransitively as a verb. Only examples which contain a preposition [lack for friends, lack in courage] are given for 'lack' as an intransitive verb in AHDEL, Collins and RHKWebster's.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But when we say 'he lacks socially/intellectually/etc', is that not intransitive?

Comment: 56 Google hits for ' "he lacks socially" -"what he lacks socially" ', and a fair proportion of these seem to be false positives ('... to compensate for all that he lacks, socially speaking.' / '... but he lacks socially acceptable behavior ...' / '... it frustrates him how much he lacks socially ...').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that last one 'it frustrates him how much he lacks socially' must be an intransitive use of lack, isn't it?

Comment: Arguable: 'How much do you lack?' 'I lack half a pound of sultanas.' v 'How much/intensely I miss you!' Call it intransitive if you like; there are still way below 50 occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, the phrase you show is correct, but 'be lacking' is preferable for this expression. However, I can see lots of examples using 'lack' not 'be lacking'.

> She lacks in patience.
>   Sam did not lack for friends

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lack

Comment: "those who be lacking intellectually"? Not sure I follow...

Comment: I did not mean that. 'be' should follow the subject-verb agreement, which means it should be 'am' for the first person singular etc.

Comment: @TylerH: This answer should probably have put **BE** in capitals, to show it's just using the "generic" infinitive as a placeholder for whatever conjugated verb form applies in any specific context. Although "grammatically" speaking your cited usage is "valid", it's dated, formal, and somewhat unidiomatic with the specific word *intellectually*.